# Linux Mint does not boot after sudden readonly file system (BIOS or SSD issue?)

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, read-only

I'm running Linux Mint (Cinnamon) on a mini PC (Zotac). Yesterday suddenly my file system become readonly (It's a 250GB SSD harddrive). I restarted the computer.
I have full disc encryption and I'm also prompted for a password in the graphical UI I'm used to. I input the password successfully. After a little wait it changes to text mode and outputs:

```
[    2.280809] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.P
RT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    2.280825] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF due to previ
ous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531)
[    2.283263] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.P
RT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    2.283271] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF due to previ
ous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531)

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Is this a BIOS issue or related to the harddrive?

What should I try next? Should I try running `fsck` or similar from the built-in shell it boots into?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some SSDs go read only when they fail. Get the data of the disk while you still can and replace it.

Comment: It's a drive issue. Nothing to do with UEFI (BIOS isn't used since ~2012 but the name stubbornly persists) in spite of the error messages that you show and that can be ignored.